# Getting Error: download failed when installing Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Today our deployment started failing out of nowhere and I noticed it was an error on the emulator installation step.

I tried it locally and got the same error:

```
> firebase setup:emulators:firestore
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.17.2.jar...
Progress: ==============================================================================================> (100% of 65MB)

Error: download failed, expected 64907894 bytes but got 64723779
```

Sounds to me like there is a problem with the latest jar version: `cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.17.2.jar`

Searched all over the place for a solution but cant find one.

Comment: This is a bug report and should be posted as an issue to [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  Stack Overflow is not likely to be of help here since the problem is not clearly with what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The issue is now solved, both links include details.

Ill leave the question open for anyone with the same problem, there was a bug reported just now:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5740

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5734

Comment: See also: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5734

This issue has now been resolved